# One way Replica deleted feature not synchronizing when I synchronize

Tags: arcgis-10.2, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, replication

I have created one-way replicas from 50 geodatabases to one geodatabase (Arcsde. With PostgSQL 9.2) After that, I update my feature class in parent geodatabase, but when I synchronize the replica the deleted feature has not been synchronized to the child geodatabase.  What can be done to make the synchronize work?

> here is replica log :
>   [image]

Comment: Sorry, what does d'not repercussions mean?

Comment: not synchronized i mean

Comment: Please edit the question to make that clear.

Comment: Have you checked the replica log to see if it is reporting success or failure?

Comment: Looks like no error is being recorded. What if you look at the replica manager in ArcCatlog. Does it list the syncs as successes or failures?(replica manager< manage replicas<rightclick<view log)

Comment: Also I'm confused about the 50 geodatabases. Does this mean 50 child replicas in geodatabase or 50 parent replicas each pushed to one child geodatabase?

Comment: thank you @Dowlers the sync has successes and i mean 50 parent replicas each pushed to one child geodatabase

Comment: Glad you got it working. You might add the solution you used as an answer to help others in the future.

Comment: I answer to your questions @Dowlers about (( 
Looks like no error is being recorded. What if you look at the replica manager in ArcCatlog. Does it list the syncs as successes or failures?(replica manager< manage replicas<rightclick<view log))) and ((Also I'm confused about the 50 geodatabases. Does this mean 50 child replicas in geodatabase or 50 parent replicas each pushed to one child geodatabase?)) but the deleted feature has not been synchronized yet !!